# Como mostrar los datos ingresados en inputs y dropdowns mediante un submit con php o javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, entrada, dropdownlist, form-submit

Muy buenas gente del foro

Lo que me gustaría hacer, lo cual no tengo la menor idea en este leguaje, es mostrar los datos que se ingresen en ciertos inputs y dropdowns en una pantalla secundaria por asi decirlo mediante un submit para que el usuario pueda tener un resumen de los datos que se llenaron en los inputs y dropdowns.

He leído que qué podría ser mediante ajax, method=GET pero soy nuevo en esto y no termino de comprenderlo.

Cualquier ayuda que me sea brindada la agradezco de antemano.

Aquí dejo un input y un dropdwon que me gustaría se mostraran en el submit:

```html
  <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">attach_money</i>
                    <input  id="MontoPresupuestado" name="MontoPresupuestado" type="number" class="validate" required title="Del Monto Presupuestado se Define Automaticamente la Modalidad/Metodología del Proceso" onchange="LoadValues()">
                    <label for="DescripcionAdquisicion">Monto Presupuestado US$</label>
                </div>
                
                
                  <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">

              <select class="browser-default" id="ModalidadProceso" name="ModalidadProceso">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione la Modalidad del Proceso</option>
                <option value="1">Pre-calificación</option>
                <option value="2">Co-Calificación</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: podrias fijarte de usar la funcion `confirm()` en javascript, la cual abre una ventana con un aceptar o cancelar

Comment: averiguare de ella ahorita y si soluciona lo que busco te aviso, gracias

Comment: @ Sacha busque la función amigo pero la verdad no es lo que quiero, ya modifique lo solicitado ya que respondiste de acuerdo a lo que pregunte, realmente lo que ocupo es simplemente que el usuario en una pantalla modal tenga un resumen de los datos ingresados en los inputs y dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es asignarle un id a cada input y ya cuando el usuario termine de llenar el formulario puedes traer los valores ingresados en cada input con Jquery y mostrarlos en un modal, ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="nombre" value="">

$("#nombre").val()
```

Así ya tienes el valor ingresado en el campo nombre, solo seria mostrarlo al final del formulario, capturando cada valor de los campos que tengas.

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, la forma más fácil para tu caso es utilizando Jquery.

Almacena el valor de los input en una variable.

html

```
   <button type="button" id="btn_prueba" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="funcionprueba()">Siguiente acción</button>
```

jquery

```
 function funcionprueba(){

 var MontoPresupuestado, ModalidadProceso;
 MontoPresupuestado = $('#MontoPresupuestado').val();
 ModalidadProceso = $('#ModalidadProceso').val();
 //Aqui todo lo que deseas realizar con el submit
 }
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

en php creo q es todo mucho más sencillo, mételo todo en un formulario con el action lo mandas a la hoja que quieras, no te olvides de poner un input submit o button según el php q uses y recoges los datos con post o gest según lo hayas puesto en el method en la hoja donde lo mandaste y pones la variable donde quieras.
http://php.net/manual/es/tutorial.forms.php